# NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces() extremely slow

Tags: c#, .net

For some reason, calls to System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces() are extremely slow, taking about 15 seconds to execute. This is new for me. I was not having this problem before, and others on my team are not having this problem with the exact same code.

Any thoughts on how to get to get to the bottom of what is causing this?

Thanks!

Comment: VS 2019 have diagnostic tools, enable CPU profiling and see what causes this. [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/beginners-guide-to-performance-profiling?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Thanks @JLOPD. I've tried using the CPU profiling feature, but am not having too much success with it (since the slowness seems to be in external code). However, when I pause the execution, it consistently shows that the lowest-level call (where the slowness appears to be occurring) is System.Net.NetworkInformation.SystemIPv4InterfaceProperties.GetPerAdapterInfo(uint index). Any insights appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @JL0PD ^^^ (adding this comment since I typed your name wrong above)

Comment: from function name I guess you have too many adapters.   I have 6 adapters returned from this function and it took 45ms. If I would had 20 adapters, it would took 1 seconds. Can't help you in any other way

Comment: OK, thank you @JL0PD. I've hardly got any devices, so I think something else is going on. But I appreciate the help.